# WPF - StylusLogic - Index was out of range

Tags: c#, wpf, touch, argumentexception

I've an WPF Application which is used by several people and sometimes I get an email with this error, but I am not able to reproduce it. Anyone got an idea what to to do get this error?

```
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusLogic.PromoteStoredItemsToMouse(StylusTouchDevice touchDevice)
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusTouchDevice.OnManipulationEnded(Boolean cancel)
   at System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice.System.Windows.Input.IManipulator.ManipulationEnded(Boolean cancel)
   at System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDevice.OnManipulationCancel()
   at System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDevice.PostProcessInput(Object sender, ProcessInputEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(ProcessInputEventHandler postProcessInput, ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDevice.ProcessManipulationInput(InputEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.ManipulationLogic.ReportFrame(ICollection`1 manipulators)
   at System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDevice.ReportFrame()
   at System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDevice.RemoveManipulator(IManipulator manipulator)
   at System.Windows.Input.Manipulation.TryRemoveManipulator(UIElement element, IManipulator manipulator)
   at System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice.PromoteMainToManipulation(UIElement manipulatableElement, TouchEventArgs touchEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice.PostProcessInput(Object sender, ProcessInputEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(ProcessInputEventHandler postProcessInput, ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice.RaiseLostCapture(IInputElement oldCapture)
   at System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice.Capture(IInputElement element, CaptureMode captureMode)
   at System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice.PromoteMainToManipulation(UIElement manipulatableElement, TouchEventArgs touchEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice.PostProcessInput(Object sender, ProcessInputEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(ProcessInputEventHandler postProcessInput, ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice.RaiseTouchUp()
   at System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice.ReportUp()
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusLogic.PromoteMainUpToTouch(StylusDevice stylusDevice, StagingAreaInputItem stagingItem)
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusLogic.PromoteMainToTouch(ProcessInputEventArgs e, StylusEventArgs stylusEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusLogic.PromoteMainToOther(ProcessInputEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusLogic.PostProcessInput(Object sender, ProcessInputEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(ProcessInputEventHandler postProcessInput, ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusLogic.InputManagerProcessInput(Object oInput)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
Methode:             Void ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
```

Answer (score 0):

Mouse input works fine but Touch causes this exception. Disabling RealTimeStylus seems to have fixed this particular issue in my case.

See http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Stylus/StylusTouchDevice.cs

Taken from a related question, which had a similar stack trace but with a different exception caused by RealTimeStylus.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15879522/3304592

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @LeeTaylor Should I be more specific? Following disabling RealTimeStylus fixes the issue without breaking functionality. Link was also provided on how to do so.